# How to send hierarchical data from firebase to google sheet

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script

below is the hierarchy of my data present in firebase database. I want to send this data to google sheet but I am unable to do so.

[image]

Error stated by google sheet is "TypeError: Cannot read property "rytf1JLXetTIINjHNku0yAvs7su2" from undefined.
Details"

Below is the code that I am trying to retrieve data. Kindly let me know the mistake. Thank you!

```
function writeSheets() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("google-sheet-id");
    var firebaseUrl = "database-url";
    var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
    var data = base.getData('users/admin');

    Logger.log(data);
    var num = 2;
    range = ss.getRange("A" + num + ":E" + num + "");
    for (var i in data) {
        var values = [
            [
                [
                    [data][data][i] // Error occurs here 
                ].email, [
                    [data][data][i] // Error occurs here 
                ].userName, [
                    [data][data] // Error occurs here 
                    [i]
                ].Password, [
                    [data][data][i]  // Error occurs here 
                ].loginState, [
                    [data][data][i]  // Error occurs here 
                ].uid
            ]
        ];
        range.setValues(values);
        num += 1;
        range = ss.getRange("A" + num + ":E" + num + "");
    }

}
```

Sample Value of data

```
{
   rytf1JLXetTIINjHNku0yAvs7su2:
      {
        loginDetail: 
            {
              uid:rytf1JLXetTIINjHNku0yAvs7su2,
              password:123456,
              loginState:true, 
              userName:John,
              email:a@a.com
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample value of ``data`` for replicating the error? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I've updated the question with sample data @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for updating it. As one more question, can I ask you about the script line that the error occurs?

Comment: yes sure, error occurs in loop var values when I am calling object within object by writing [data][data] @Tanaike

Comment: Does the error occur at ``range.setValues(values)``?

Comment: I've updated the question where error occurs @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the output you want? By this, I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question and comments, I thought that you want to do as follows.

- You want to put the values of `"email", "userName", "password", "loginState", "uid"` to the Spreadsheet every row.
- You want to put the value from 2nd row of the 1st sheet in the Spreadsheet.
- The structure of object `data` is like as follows. You want to retrieve each value from the object `loginDetail`.

  ```
  {
    "rytf1JLXetTIINjHNku0yAvs7su2": {
      "loginDetail": {
        "uid": "rytf1JLXetTIINjHNku0yAvs7su2",
        "password": 123456,
        "loginState": true,
        "userName": "John",
        "email": "a@a.com"
      }
    }
  };
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- Find `loginDetail` at the 2nd level, and the object of `loginDetail` is retrieved.
- From the retrieved object `loginDetail`, each value of `"email", "userName", "password", "loginState", "uid"` is retrieved in order.
- Values of `"email", "userName", "password", "loginState", "uid"` are put from the 2nd row of 1st sheet of the Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

```
function writeSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("google-sheet-id");
  var firebaseUrl = "database-url";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData('users/admin');

  Logger.log(data);

  // I modified below script.
  var keys = ["email", "userName", "password", "loginState", "uid"];
  var res = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    for (var j in data[i]) {
      if (j == "loginDetail") {
        res.push(keys.map(function(e) {return data[i][j][e]}));
      }
    }
  }
  var num = 2;
  ss.getRange("A" + num + ":E" + (res.length + num - 1)).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Note:

- If the structure of object `data` is changed, it is required to traverse the object. At that time, please tell me.

#### Reference:

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: @Ghulam Ahmed Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.