# How can I write in Google Sheets my Firebase data?

Tags: json, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a database in Firebase, and I want to get the data from there and put them in a Google SpreadSheet.

```
function getData() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Database");
var data = getFirebaseData('contacts');
var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()];
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,1);
Logger.log(data)
range.setValue(data)
}

function getFirebaseData(data){
var firebaseUrl = "https://XXXXX.firebaseio.com/";
var secret = 'XXXXXXXX';
var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret);
var result = base.getData('contacts');
for(var i in data) {
    Logger.log(data[i].eMail + ' ' + data[i].title);
return result;
 }
}
```

and here the image:

[image: databse]

No data is shown, and I cannot understand why

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56325238

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be solved by completing several steps:

1. In your `getFirebaseData()` function, move the `return` statement outside of the loop;
2. Instead of looping over `data`, loop over `result` (currently, you iterate over each property of the "contacts" `String`);
3. Optionally, add checks for `getData()` returning `null` or invalid `firebaseUrl` (in the last case, `getData()` will cause an error, use `try...catch` to account for that);
4. Change `base.getData('contacts')` to `base.getData(data)` (isn't it
   the reason you pass `data` to the function?);